# Making multidimensional slice from multidimensional array does not work as expected

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a multidimensional slice from a multidimensional array and some strange things are happening (at least for me). I created a multidimensional array `ma` and made three slices `s1`, `s2`, `s3` from it. The code below shows this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var ma [4][3]int32 = [4][3]int32{
        {10, 20, 30},
        {50, 60, 70},
        {80, 90, 100},
        {110, 120, 130},
    }

    var s1 [][3]int32 = ma[:]       // expected

    var s2 [][3]int32 = ma[:][:]    // ????

    var s3 [][]int32 = ma[0:2][0:2] // ????
}
```

`var s1 [][3]int32 = ma[:]` behaves as expected. `ma[:]` creates a slice of [3]int32 arrays, so we have an underlaying array with each element of type [3]int32 array. Tottally expected behaviour for me.

Problems arise when defining s1 and s2. It's not behaving as I expected. `var s2 [][3]int32 = ma[:][:]` gives the same result as `var s1 [][3]int32 = ma[:]`. I expected it to make a slice of slices, not a slice of arrays. How is it possible? How can the two give the same result?

Additionally, I expect `var s3 [][]int32 = ma[0:2][0:2]` to create a slice of slices as well. Instead it gives the error "*cannot use ma[0:2][0:2] (value of type [][3]int32) as [][]int32 value in variable declaration compiler*". So somehow, with `ma[0:2][0:2]` it gives the type `[][3]int32`, not `[][]int32`. How?

I hope I have explained what is not clear to me.

Comment: A "multidimensional" array have multiple arrays, and a "multidimensional" slice have multiple slices. A slicing operation creates a single slice from an array, so you can't have what you want with one or two slicing. Slice the "outer" array, and use a loop to slice all elements too.

Comment: The expression `ma[:][:]` parses as `(ma[:])[:]`. The expression evaluates a [slice expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) on the result of the slice expresion on `ma`.   The outer slice expression is a noop. The expression is not a multidimensional slice expression.

Comment: In other words, there is no "multidimensional slice syntax" in the Go language. Whether you have invented this yourself, or adopted it from another language, it is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks! I did not find an answer to my question on stackoverflow. It would be good if you could write it as an "official answer" so that I can mark my question as solved. I think it will help many beginners.

Comment: @JimB var slices [][]int32 = [][]int32{{10, 20}, {30, 40}, {50, 60}}. This is not "multidimensional slice"?

Comment: @BruzziElMuerte: but you're not asking about a slice data type, which can of course contain nested slices -- you are asking about [slice expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions), which have no syntax for iterating over nested slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `ma[:][:]` parses as `(ma[:])[:]`.  The expression evaluates to a [slice expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) on the result of the slice expression on `ma`.  The outer slice expression is a noop.

Go does not have multidimensional slice expressions.